# using infinite scrolling neither onRowDataChanged or onRowDataUpdated get called

Tags: ag-grid

When using infinite scrolling on the agGrid, neither of these 2 events ever get called.  Is there a way to capture that data has been updated?

Here is my grid configuration

```
    <ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  id="ri-search"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [components]="components"
  [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
  [rowDeselection]="true"
  [rowModelType]="'infinite'"
  [paginationPageSize]="10"
  [cacheBlockSize]="100"
  [cacheOverflowSize]="2"
  [maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests]="2"
  [infiniteInitialRowCount]="1"
  [maxBlocksInCache]="2"
  [pagination]="true"
  [paginationAutoPageSize]="true"
  [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (onRowDataUpdated)="onGotData1($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

and here is the event handler

```
  onGotData1(params){
    console.info('hi');
  }
```

on got data never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `(rowDataUpdated)="onGotData1($event)"`. You are expecting wrong event.

Reference: [Grid Events](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#miscellaneous)

Similarly, `rowDataChanged` is another event you are looking for.

Comment: still does not fire.  actually neither fire

Comment: It should work. Could you check in one of the plunk provided in the reference link?  Also, if you could create a plunk with your issue reproduced, it would be easier to troubleshoot where you are facing the challenge.